# Cross referencing sql tables php

Tags: php, sql

I will try and explain this as best I can, any questions please ask:

I have three tabels -

- tblOrderProducts
- tblOrders
- tblProducts

tblOrders contains the order details but not the actual products that the customer has ordered, so I need to cross referrence the tables:

VendorTxCode is a field in both **tblOrders** and **tblOrderProducts**.

**tblOrderProducts** contains the following:

**VendorTxCode | ProductId |    Price | Quantity**
651                              1                 42.50      1
651                              4                  3.99       4

**tblProducts** has the these fields:

**ProductId |   Price | Description**
1                    42.50      Chicken
4                     3.99       Egg

So my question is how would be able to display the product description and quantity of each item order by the VendorTxCode:

Thanks for lookin and I hope you can help I was up til 4am this morning trying all diferent ways without sucess.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which sql flavor you are using, but something along these lines:

```
select 
 p.Description
,op.Price
,op.quantity
from tblOrderProducts op
 inner join tblProducts p on p.ProductId = op.ProductId
where op.VendorTxCode = @YourVendorTxCode
```